# Complexity of counting MAXCUT in planar graphs -- seemingly contradicting claims

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

Confusion is likely. Appears to me two papers give contradicting claims
about the complexity of counting MAXCUT in planar graphs.

[Exact Max 2-SAT: Easier and Faster p. 6](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~kasivisw/save1.pdf)

> However, counting the number of Max 2-Sat or Max Cut solutions are
>   $\#P$-complete even when restricted to planar graphs (results not explicitly stated but follow readily from results and reductions in [13, 20]).

[13] H. B. Hunt III, M. V. Marathe, V. Radhakrishnan, and R. E. Stearns, The complexity of planar counting problems, SIAM Journal of Computing 27 (1998), no. 4, 1142–1167.

[20] S. P. Vadhan, The complexity of counting in sparse, regular, and planar graphs, SIAM Journal of
Computing 31 (2002), no. 2, 398–427.

[Exponential Time Complexity of the Permanent and the Tutte Polynomial p. 13](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.1775)

> Proposition 4.1. If #ETH holds, the coefficients of the polynomial w → Z(G; 2, w) for a given simple graph G cannot be computed in time exp(o(m)).
>   Proof. The reduction is from #MaxCut and well-known
>   ...Now, the coefficient of $(1 + w)^{m-c}$ in $Z(G; 2, w)$ is the number of cuts in $G$ of size $c$.

The Tutte polynomial on the hyperbola $(x-1)(y-1)=2$ is polynomially
computable on planar graphs and (4) on the same page gives
$Z(G;2,w)$ in terms of the Tutte polynomial on the hyperbola.

The first paper doesn't define MAXCUT, but assuming the usual definition,
 the two papers imply $P=\#P$.

> What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 6):

There was some discussion about this claim at the [Dagstuhl seminar on Computational Counting](https://www.dagstuhl.de/en/program/calendar/semhp/?semnr=13031) in 2013. The technique you give to calculate #MAX-CUT is correct and it is not obvious how the hardness result is meant to "follow readily" from the two papers referenced, so I think it should be assumed that the claim of #P-hardness is in error.

I e-mailed Martin Fürer about this shortly after the seminar, and received no response.

Comment: Thanks. I emailed the authors of the first paper yesterday.